# What is the equation for the error of the Newton-Raphson method?

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

The title says it all:

What is the equation for the error of the Newton-Raphson method?

Also... an explanation for each of the terms would be nice... I'm a comp sci guy, not typically a math guy.

Comment: This shouldn't really be tagged comp-sci... I'm retagging as calculus and numerical methods.

Also, can you give us some more information? For example, how you're trying to use Newton's method and what terms are confusing you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose you're using Newton-Raphson to solve $f(x)=0$ where $f$ is a twice differentiable function, so $x_{n+1} = x_n  - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$, and $f(r) = 0$.  Then 
$$r - x_{n+1} = - \frac{f''(c) (r - x_n)^2}{2 f'(x_n)}$$
where $c$ is some point between $r$ and $x_n$.  If $f''$ is continuous, $f'(r) \ne 0$ and $x_n$ is close to $r$, $f''(c)/f'(x_n)$ will be close to $f''(r)/f'(r)$, so this says the error in $x_{n+1}$ is approximately a constant times the square of the error in $x_n$.

Comment: For the record, this is a consequence of [Taylor' theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem).